# Why is the behavior of PR base branch deletion different between GitHub and AWS CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, merge, aws-codecommit

Hello consider the following scenario, There is a "Dev" branch and two feature branches "A" and "B", "B" will merge into "A" and finally "A" will merge into "Dev" branch this flow can be easily understood by following diagram. Note that after merging the merged branch will be deleted immediately.

[image]

**Now though, I want to setup 2 Pull Requests, one for "B" into "A", and another for "A" into "Dev", and then test what happens if I merge "A" into "Dev" first.**

When I merge "A" branch into "Dev" branch then simply "A" branch is removed instantly and what happens next is a bit interesting:

**GitHub**

The GitHub changes the base of the branch "B" to the "Dev" branch as, which obviously make sense because "Dev" now contains all the code which was present in "A", so when "B" is merged technically "Dev" contains the work of both "A" and "B", this totally makes sense and its the desired behavior.

**AWS Code Commit**

The problem rise here, when the same operation is performed in AWS code commit, the "A" is merged into "Dev" but now due to the deletion of "A" the "B" branch cannot be merged into "A" anymore, so "B" branch is closed automatically by AWS code commit, which leads to the partial work in "Dev" branch.

**The Main Question**

How do i achieve the behavior of GitHub in AWS code commit ?

Comment: My understanding is you want to do this in order: 1) Merge B into A and delete B. 2.) Merge A into Dev and delete A. If you do both of those in the same order in both GitHub and AWS, I assume you'll get the same result.

Comment: Oh... after reading this multiple times, it just occurred to me that maybe you left out an important detail. Is the picture what the perfect scenario is, but then you are testing what would happen if you merged A into Dev **before** merging B into A? And if you do this, it seems to behave differently? (Is that the question here?)

Comment: Thats the tricky part @TTT that github handles some how itself it changes the base means merging B branch will directly  incorporated in Dev

Comment: Exactly @TTT this is what i am testing without merging branch B into A if we break the chain and merge A into Dev then how the B is handeled . for now i like the github way but code commit is not doing it according to the desired way

Comment: Yes your last comment is right and this is what i have observed but not only for observation i am looking a way to configure code commit so that i can achieve the behaviour of github merging process

Comment: Got it. I edited the question to make this clearer (and cleaning up some irrelevant comments now.)

Comment: Are you talking about Pull Requests in both GitHub and CodeCommit? For example, you have a PR setup going from B to A, in both tools, and GitHub is changing the target branch from A to Dev automatically after A is deleted, whereas CodeCommit is just automatically closing the PR after A is deleted?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment- if it's in the context of a PR, I'm surprised either of those happens automatically! If you weren't talking about PRs here, then what do you mean by "The GitHub changes the base of the branch "B" to the "Dev" branch" and also ""B" branch is closed automatically" ?

Comment: @TTT its about PR

Comment: OK. I edited again and I think we now have a clear question. (At least clear to me!) ;)

Comment: I think we can delete all of these comments now, as they are all captured in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247737/discussion-between-ttt-and-zain-ul-abidin). (Well that didn't work- I want all of these comments in chat...moderator help?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the behavior of PR base branch deletion different between GitHub and AWS CodeCommit?

That's just the way it is.

Note that Pull Requests aren't actually a part of Git itself, but instead are a common feature that many tools implement. Some tools don't even call them "Pull Requests"! (GitLab, for example, calls them "Merge Requests, which IMHO is a slightly better name.) In most workflows, the *base* branch, also know as a *target* branch of a Pull Request, is typically a long-lived branch, so it wouldn't commonly be deleted while other Pull Requests are pointing to it. It's not surprising then that each tool implements this case a little differently. You're observations of the differences are documented:

GitHub's implementation of automatically changing the PR base branch is documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches#working-with-branches):

> If you delete a head branch after its pull request has been merged, GitHub checks for any open pull requests in the same repository that specify the deleted branch as their base branch. GitHub automatically updates any such pull requests, changing their base branch to the merged pull request's base branch.

AWS CodeCommit's implementation of automatically closing a PR when the base branch is deleted is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-merge-pull-request.html):

> CodeCommit closes a pull request automatically if either the source or destination branch of the pull request is deleted.

Unfortunately, I can't find documentation that either implementation is configurable, so it seems you won't be able to change it. If you like how GitHub does it, in AWS CodeCommit I think you'll either have to re-open the PR and change the base branch yourself, or create a new PR.

Comment: Thanks TTT, you explained very well and now after reading the documentations you highlighted, everything is now clear to me